# DB2 CLI result output

Tags: db2

When running command-line queries in MySQL you can optionally use '**\G**' as a statement terminator, and instead of the result set columns being listed horizontally across the screen, it will list each column vertically, which the corresponding data to the right. Is there a way to the same or a similar thing with the DB2 command line utility?

Example regular MySQL result

```
mysql> select * from tagmap limit 2;
+----+---------+--------+
| id | blog_id | tag_id |
+----+---------+--------+
| 16 |       8 |      1 |
| 17 |       8 |      4 |
+----+---------+--------+
```

Example Alternate MySQL result:

```
mysql> select * from tagmap limit 2\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
     id: 16
blog_id: 8
 tag_id: 1
*************************** 2. row ***************************
     id: 17
blog_id: 8
 tag_id: 4
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Obviously, this is much more useful when the columns are large strings, or when there are many columns in a result set, but this demonstrates the formatting better than I can probably explain it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think such an option is available with the DB2 command line client. See http://www.dbforums.com/showthread.php?t=708079 for some suggestions. For a more general set of information about the DB2 command line client you might check out the IBM DeveloperWorks article [DB2's Command Line Processor and Scripting](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/db2/library/techarticle/adamache/0109adamache.html).

Answer (score 0):

Little bit late, but found this post when I searched for an option to retrieve only the selected data.

So `db2 -x <query>` gives only the result back. More options can be found here: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.1?topic=clp-options

Example:

```
[db2inst1@a21c-db2 db2]$ db2 -n select postschemaver from files.product

POSTSCHEMAVER                   
--------------------------------
147.3                           

  1 record(s) selected.

[db2inst1@a21c-db2 db2]$ db2 -x select postschemaver from files.product        
147.3
```

Answer (score -2):

DB2 command line utility always displays data in tabular format. i.e. rows horizontally and columns vertically. It does not support any other format like \G statement terminator do for mysql. But yes, you can store column organized data in DB2 tables when DB2_WORKLOAD=ANALYTICS is set.

```
db2 => connect to coldb

   Database Connection Information

 Database server        = DB2/LINUXX8664 10.5.5
 SQL authorization ID   = BIMALJHA
 Local database alias   = COLDB

db2 => create table testtable (c1 int, c2 varchar(10)) organize by column
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.
db2 => insert into testtable values (2, 'bimal'),(3, 'kumar')
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.
db2 => select * from testtable

C1          C2        
----------- ----------
          2 bimal     
          3 kumar     

  2 record(s) selected.

db2 => terminate
DB20000I  The TERMINATE command completed successfully.
```